# return value for operator + ( ) overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value

Why compiler doesn't return  error if `operator+()` member function  of `date` class is not returning anything. if i do

```
date d1,d2;
date any = d1 + d2;
```

then  `d1 + d2`  will create a temporary, what does this temporary gets initialized with?

```
date operator+(date d)  
{  
    day += d.day; 
    month += d.month; 
    year += d.year; 
}
```

Note: its  just for test purpose only. Not for commercial use or anything.

Comment: I also think you need to reconsider your implementation - otherwise you are going to get odd results like 60th of the 15th month!

Comment: What's the point of adding *dates*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, it's `operator +()` and not `operator +=()`, you should be creating a temporary and return the same:

```
date operator + (const date &d) const
{            //  ^^^^ 1         ^^^^^ 2
  date temp = *this;  // copy current object
  ...
  return temp;  // important: -Wall warned you for missing 'return'
}
```

There are other 2 important changes you can see:

(1) Passing `d` as `const` reference; because you don't need another copy

(2) Making `operator +` as `const` correct by adding `const` at end; because you are not going to  modify `this` object

**Update**: For your updated question, here is a link which answers it.

[Why “not all control paths return a value” is warning and not an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735038/why-not-all-control-paths-return-a-value-is-warning-and-not-an-error)

Comment: +1 for using a reference constant parameter. too many people use "stack" non-reference non-pointer arguments for non-predefined types!

Comment: It might be worth adding that the usual idiom here is 1) to make `operator+` a free function (but this is certainly not necessary unless there are implicit conversions to `date`) and 2) to implement it in terms of `operator+=`.  (You've also got several instances of `data` which should be `date`.)

Comment: +1 for the sample code with the correct function prototype for operator+

Comment: @vulkanino if a date is only a few bytes, pass-by-value could be faster

Answer (score 2):

**What does the following overloaded operator of date class should return? I see that it returns garbage.**

You are not returning anything from the function, and hence the value returned is any randowm value and it is an **Undefined Behavior**.

You should return an object of the type `Date` explicitly by using :

```
return objName;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're modifying the first operand of `+`, which is incorrect. Get a copy and return it:

```
date operator+(date d) const { 
    date r = *this;
    r.day += d.day; r.month += d.month; r.year += d.year;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An object of type `date`.

You should construct a new date and not do the `+=` of the various components. This is due to you wanting the + operator to behave in the traditional way as the + operator for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way but create a new object to return.
Don't worry about copying temporary object, most compilers would using NRVO here.