# C++ code Stopped Working Error using cout inside function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

My Code doesnt work when I use cout inside a function but if I return the value and stream inside main function it works.
My code which does not work is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int add(int a,int b){
  int c = a+b;
  cout<<c<<endl;
}
string add(string m,string n){
  string c = m+" "+n;
  cout<<c<<endl;
}
int main(){
    string x ="amit";
    string y ="kumar";
    add(x,y);//adding string
    add(5,58);//adding numbers
}
```

But when I return the value it works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int add(int a,int b){
  int c = a+b;
  cout<<c<<endl;
}
string add(string m,string n){
  string c = m+" "+n;
  return c;
}
int main(){
    string x ="amit";
    string y ="kumar";
    string z = add(x,y);

    cout<<z<<endl;
    add(5,58);//adding numbers
}
```

I am using Codeblocks for my programming. Why is this abrupt behaviour. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: The program is just existing, closing the console, and you're unable to see the output. Run from the command shell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096027/function-returning-stdstring-crashes-without-return-statement-unlike-a-functi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your programs have [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

`string add(string m,string n)` and `int add(int a,int b)` have declared `non-void` return types. But the functions flows of the end without a `return` statement that returns anything. That causes undefined behavior.

If you add a proper return statement or change the declared return type to `void` it will work as expected in both programs.

If you haven't yet, enable additional warnings in your compiler. It should have warned you about this problem. If it did warn you, then please never ignore warnings. Fix all of them.

---

Also note that you need to `#include<string>`, not `#include<cstring>`, to use `std::string`.

Comment: Why the same is not happening in case of int why only string?

Comment: @AmitRay It is *undefined behavior*. You have no guarantee that anything specific will happen. I have updated my answer to clarify that both programs have undefined behavior.